# Serial No in Sql FROM TO TO

Tags: sql-server

This is my  primary table structure .i  have to generate the serial no in this format in  second table 
Table Name-#T

```
SRL  CustomerCode      TotalIssue        No         TotalAmount 
1   C05515001001            16           100          1600
2   C05515001002            2            100          200
3   C05515001003            2            100          200
4   C05515001004            1            100          100
5   C05515001005            9            100          900
```

Structure of second table is like this

Table name-#TBLMember

```
SRL CustomerCode  TotalIssue  DistinctFrom   DistinctTo  No    Amount
 1  C05515001001    16         1543391        1543391    100    1600
 2  C05515001002    2          1543392        1543392    100    200
 3  C05515001003    2          1543393        1543393    100    200
 4  C05515001004    1          1543394        1543394    100    100
 5  C05515001005    9          1543395        1543395    100    900
```

Default Value of DistinctFrom   =1543391
                 DistinctTo     =1543391

Initially second table is blank so i am getting these value using this queries

```
declare @DistinctiveNoFrom bigint=(select isnull(MAX(DistinctiveNoFrom),(1543390)) from #TBLMember)

declare @DistinctiveNoTo bigint=(select isnull(MAX(DistinctiveNoTo),(1543390)) from #TBLMember)
```

Then I am inserting into this table :-

```
insert into #TBLMember(CustomerCode,TotalSharesIssue,No ,TotalAmount )
select c.customerCode,c.TotalIssue,@No,@No*c.TotalIssue
FROM #T c
```

But result is not expected.I want result like this

```
SRL CustomerCode    TotalIssue  DistincFrom DistinctTo  No  TotalAmount
1   C05515001001        16       1543391    1543407     100   1600
2   C05515001002         2       1543407    1543409     100    200
3   C05515001003         2       1543409    1543411     100    200
4   C05515001004         1       1543411    1543412     100    100
5   C05515001005         9       1543412    1543421     100    900
```

Please help me i am fed up.
thanks in advance.

Comment: What sql server version are you working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 declare @membershipno bigint=(select isnull(MAX(MemberShipNo),(821931))  from #TBL_MemberShareCertificate)
 declare @DistinctiveNoFrom bigint=(select isnull(MAX(DistinctiveNoFrom),(1543390)) from #TBL_MemberShareCertificate)
 declare @DistinctiveNoTo bigint=(select isnull(MAX(DistinctiveNoTo),(1543390)) from #TBL_MemberShareCertificate)
 declare @CertificateNo bigint=(select isnull(MAX(CertificateNo),(822004)) from #TBL_MemberShareCertificate)
 declare @NominalValue_of_Shares float=100

;WITH CTE2
 AS
(
SELECT  C.SRL,C.Code,
cast(c.membershipno as BIGINT)membershipno,
 c.CertificateNo,
 C.TotalSharesIssue,
 (@DistinctiveNoFrom+1) as DistinctiveNoFrom,
 CAST(((@DistinctiveNoFrom+1)+c.TotalSharesIssue) 
 as BIGINT)AS DistinctiveNoTo
,c.NominalValue_of_Shares
,c.TotalAmount,c.MemberCeasedDate,c.Remarks
FROM #CUST C WHere C.SRL=1
UNION ALL
SELECT A.SRL,
    A.Code,cast(A.membershipno as BIGINT)membershipno,A.CertificateNo,
    A.TotalSharesIssue,
    B.DistinctiveNoTo+1 as DistinctiveNoFrom ,
    CAST((B.DistinctiveNoTo+1 + A.TotalSharesIssue) AS BIGINT)as DistinctiveNoTo,
    A.NominalValue_of_Shares,
    A.TotalAmount,A.MemberCeasedDate,A.Remarks
FROM #CUST A
INNER JOIN CTE2 B ON A.SRL  = B.SRL+1
)

INSERT INTO #TBL_MemberShareCertificate(SRL,MemberShipNo,CustomerCode,
    TotalSharesIssue,  DistinctiveNoFrom,DistinctiveNoTo,
     NominalValue_of_Shares,TotalAmount,CertificateNo,
     MemberCeasedDate,Remarks)
   SELECT C.SRL,C.membershipno,C.Code,C.TotalSharesIssue,
   C.DistinctiveNoFrom,C.DistinctiveNoTo,C.NominalValue_of_Shares,
 C.TotalAmount,C.CertificateNo,C.MemberCeasedDate,C.Remarks 
   FROM CTE2 C  OPTION(maxrecursion 0);

 **
```

- **assume that #cust table created.**

**

Answer (score 0):

Use a `OUTER APPLY` OR `SUM OVER()` depending on your SQL Server version.

**OUTER APPLY**

```
declare @DistinctiveNoFrom bigint=(select isnull(MAX(DistinctiveNoFrom),(1543390)) from #TBLMember)

insert into #TBLMember(CustomerCode,TotalSharesIssue,No ,TotalAmount )
select c.customerCode,c.TotalIssue, @DistinctiveNoFrom +ISNULL(c2.prevIssue,0), @DistinctiveNoFrom + ISNULL(c2.prevIssue,0) + c.TotalIssue, 100 as No,c.TotalIssue*100
FROM #T c
OUTER APPLY(
SELECT SUM(TotalIssue) prevIssue
FROM #T c2 
WHERE c2.customerCode < c.customerCode) as c2
```

**SUM() OVER(ORDER BY)** works with SQL Server 2012 onwards

```
declare @DistinctiveNoFrom bigint=(select isnull(MAX(DistinctiveNoFrom),(1543390)) from #TBLMember)

insert into #TBLMember(CustomerCode,TotalSharesIssue,No ,TotalAmount )
select c.customerCode,c.TotalIssue, @DistinctiveNoFrom + SUM(TotalIssue) OVER(ORDER BY customerCode ASC ROWS PRECEDING), @DistinctiveNoFrom + SUM(TotalIssue) OVER(ORDER BY customerCode ASC), 100 as No,c.TotalIssue*100
FROM #T c
```

Comment: my dear friend why did u use the variable when r u not using them.it's Worng bro

Comment: @Ramdeoangh - I took the names from your sql in the question. Completely overlooked that the variable names were different in the query and declare statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following recursion common table expression query, assuming that the SRL is serial number with no gap

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1 SRL,
        CustomerCode,
        TotalIssue,
        DistinctFrom,
        DistinctFrom + TotalIssue AS DistinctTo,
        No,
        Amount
    FROM TblMember

    UNION ALL

    SELECT TblMember.SRL,
        TblMember.CustomerCode,
        TblMember.TotalIssue,
        CTE.DistinctTo AS DistinctFrom,
        CTE.DistinctTo + TblMember.TotalIssue AS DistinctTo,
        TblMember.No,
        TblMember.Amount
    FROM CTE
    JOIN TblMember ON CTE.SRL + 1 = TblMember.SRL

)
SELECT * FROM CTE;
```

Comment: Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "DistinctiveTo" of recursive query "CTE".

Comment: Updated the query, can you check?

Comment: it's right bro thanks  by reference your  query i done this.thanks.find below the  whole code.